# How to take backup of a firebase database from Google Cloud Engine using cURL?

Tags: curl, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-compute-engine, firebase-security

I was taking backup of my firebase db using cURL on Google Compute engine. The backups were successful last week. Two days before I changed the security of my db to allow only authenticated users to read or write. 
Something like this

```
{
  "rules": {
        ".read": "auth != null",
        ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

Now my backup started failing. So, how do I add or grant the user in compute engine to successfully take backup of my firebase database? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned in your other answer, you are now using the **Firebase Admin SDK**, so I'll include a very simple app that does what you are looking for (downloads your database and saves it as a JSON file).

For this script, I am going to assume that what you were trying to do is something like:

```
curl https://YOUR-PROJECT.firebaseio.com/.json?format=export -o backup-20170606.json
```

In case someone needs them, setup instructions for the Firebase Admin SDK can be found [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#add_firebase_to_your_app).

### The Script

```
var fs = require('fs'); // Node.js Internal Module
var path = require('path'); // Node.js Internal Module
var moment = require('moment'); // External module

var admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp(/* Service account details go here */);

// Change these as desired
var outFileName = 'backup_' + moment().format('YYYYMMDD_HH-mm-ss');
var outFileDir = '/tmp';
var outFilePath = path.join(outFileDir, outFileName);

var rootRef = admin.database().ref(); // Ref to database root
rootRef.once("value", function(snapshot){
  var outText = JSON.stringify(snapshot.val());
  fs.writeFile(outFilePath, outText, function(err) {
    if(err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }
    console.log("The file was saved as '" + outFilePath + "'!");
  });
});
```

*Note:* `moment.js` isn't explicitly required, it's just a really useful module I use often.

### Things to Consider

- You should download the database in pieces (see [`orderByKey()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data#section-queries)) and save each entry into a buffer and then to disk upon completed download. The current code will struggle with big databases.
- The download will be slow depending on the database size. Consider parallelizing it.

### Alternatives

You can also use the [Firebase Tools](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools#database-commands) to access/download/manipulate your database.

Answer (score 0):

Since, I enabled the authentication of the database, I am not able to take the backup without authenticating the server.

To overcome, I used [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) with a service account. After that I am able to access the Firebase database using the [APIs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/start)